# Search all tds of a table for the exact string "Retired" in it; if true, hide the entire row of that table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem is I want to find the exact string "Retired" in each of the tds of a table. If any td contains this string, hide the entire parent row in the table.

To give you an idea of the structure of the table, here's the code:

```
<table id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00">
```

```
    <td class="keyField"><a id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl06_f35458:17503c">RSK-089871</a></td>

    <td><div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl04_f35458:17732c">
        <div class="SelectedOverFlowDiv"><div><a id="762197-14764c" class="ContentURL">PR-007785</a></div></div>
    </div></td>

    <td><span id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl04_f35458:27843c">test1</span></td>

    <td><div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl04_f35458:34835c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines"><li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast"><div class="rtMid"><div style="color:#000000;">RETIRED</div></div></li></ul>
    </div></td>
</tr>

<tr id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00__1" >
    <td class="keyField"><a id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl06_f35458:17503c">RSK-089870</a></td>

    <td><div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl06_f35458:17732c">
        <div class="SelectedOverFlowDiv"><div><a id="768857-14764c">PR-008899</a></div></div>
    </div></td>

    <td><span id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl06_f35458:27843c">Securitization (ABS) (REG AB COMPLIANCE)</span></td>

    <td><div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s5131_f35458srvgrid_ctl00_ctl06_f35458:34835c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines"><li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast" id=""><div class="rtMid"><div style="color:#000000;">PENDING</div></div></li></ul>
    </div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `:contains()` selector along with `.closest()` to achieve what you want,

```
$("table tbody tr td:contains('Retired')").closest("tr").hide();
```

But keep in mind that `:contains()` selector is case-sensitive.

Comment: does the 'table' has to be the table id? Sorry, really new to jquery!

Comment: @TanveerShaikh Yeah. You can use your table id there in the selector instead of table. I have used tag selector, you can use id selector too.